# Determining the physical height of a gaussian curve (python)

Tags: python, gaussian

In fitting a Gaussian to a curve, the model of my Gaussian is defined as:

```
def model(position, width, height):
    return  height * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, position, width)
```

However, the height variable in the model is not the true height, or peak value, of the curve. For the example shown below, using a height variable of 1.0 and a width of 0.1, the peak value of the Gaussian is 4.0.

```
import numpy
import pylab
import scipy.stats, scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 400)
def model(position, width, height):
    return  height * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, position, width)
position = 0.5
height = 1.0
width = 0.1

gauss = model(position, width, height)
plt.plot(x,gauss, '+', color='red')
show()
```

Is there some way to determine what the peak value of the Gaussian will be from the width and height variables in my model? I realize this may be more of a mathematical question than a coding question. Nonetheless, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I am using this model to fit curves that need to be 3*sigma higher than the noise surrounding them. It is unclear to me how to set a lower boundary condition for the height variable that corresponds to the Gaussian model having a peak value of 3*sigma. For example, if I know 3*sigma is 0.1, how do I convert that into a height variable value to define my lower boundary condition correctly?

Cheers,

TFish13

Comment: Normal pdfs are greatest at their mean. So you can use `height*scipy.stats.norm.pdf(0, scale=width)` to get the maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that I needed to normalize the Gaussian first before multiplying it by a height variable to correctly scale it to the height of the data. As such, the correct model is:

```
def model(position, width, height):
    return  height * sqrt(2*pi) * width * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, position, width)
```

Now the height variable in the model will match the peak height of the plotted Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the gaussian at any point x is exactly scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,position,width). If you wanted to scale the whole gaussian up to a certain value, so the peak is at a value, say 4, then try something along the lines of

```
def model(position, width, height):
    return  (height / scipy.stats.norm.pdf(position,position,width)) * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, position, width)
```

By dividing the whole distribution by the value at the peak (which occurs at point 'position') the whole distribution is stretched vertically so that the peak has value 1. Then by multiplying by your height parameter, you'll scale the distribution so the peak has value height.

This is indeed a mathematical question, not a programming one, but we see many of these questions here anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your input! To clarify, I am using this model to fit curves that need to be 3*sigma higher than the noise surrounding them. It is unclear to me how to define the lower boundary condition for the height variable that corresponds to the Gaussian model having a peak value of 3*sigma. For example, if I know 3*sigma is 0.1, how do I convert that into a height variable value to define my lower boundary condition correctly?